# File cannot be updated in external storage

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, file-permissions

I have a file in storage and I'm trying to write data into that file. But an exception os thrown.

```kotlin
val file = File(myFilePath)
val data : String = my_data
var bW: BufferedWriter
try {
    bW = BufferedWriter(FileWriter(file, true));
    bW.write(data);
    bW.newLine();
    bW.flush();
    bW.close();
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.d("log", "error = $e")
}
```

The error I'm getting

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/myFolder/myFile.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

I have placed the file in above path and I cross checked frequently that the file exists there. But why I'm getting `FileNotFoundException` I don't know.

My Android version is `10 QP1A` and mobile I'm using `redmi note 8 pro`.

I tried all solutions that exists (5 to 8 years old) and nothing was working.

Comment: what's the value of myFilePath ?

Comment: @User9211 `/storage/emulated/0/Download/myFolder/myFile.txt` I'm able to open it and when i edit and save. I can't see the reflections

Comment: Add this to your Manifest file - android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"    .. and minSdkVersion 29  ..it should work then!! Try this and tell me? @rock

Comment: @User9211 I have added and it's same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For API 29 (Android 10),

1. Ensure you have `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` granted.
2. Add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your application element in your manifest file. [Reference](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage)

E.g.

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<manifest ...>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        ...
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyActivity.kt

```kotlin
...

        val permissionStatus = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        if(permissionStatus == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                writeToFile()
            }
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
        }

...

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if(grantResults.all { it == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED }) {
            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                writeToFile()
            }
        }
    }

...

    @WorkerThread
    private fun writeToFile() {
        val file = File(<myFilePath>)
        val data = <my_data>

        with(BufferedWriter(FileWriter(file, true))) {
            write(data)
            newLine()
            flush()
            close()
        }
    }
}
```